# Populate Select with values from JSON

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I'm having an issue with `[formGroup]` ( working with **Angular 8** ), I have a component that check `onInit` if the users already have a project or not and render values depending on the response, if there's values then I use the `[selected]` option to render them which actually works but only the visual part cause when I try to `POST` the selected values my Validator tells me that there's none, here's an example :

[image: Validators]

If anyone got a hint on what's the issue, I'll be glad to hear it

**Pricelist & currency DIV (project.component.html)**

```
    <div>
<form [formGroup]="registerForm">
 <div class="flex2 pl10">
  <select formControlName="pricelist" class="form-control" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': submitted && f.pricelist.errors}" (change)="selectedPriceListIndex = $event.target.value">
     <option value="" > Select a pricelist </option>
     <option  *ngFor="let p of filter.ListPricelist; let i = index;" [selected]="p.id === project?.pricelist_id" [value]="i"  id="pricelist_id" value="{{p.id === project?.pricelist_id}}"  >{{ p.label }}</option>
   </select>
   <div *ngIf="submitted && f.pricelist.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
     <div *ngIf="f.pricelist.errors.required">Pricelist is required</div>
   </div>
 </div>
   <div class="flex2 pl10">
    <select formControlName="currency" [ngClass]="{'is-invalid': submitted && f.currency.errors}" class="form-control">
     <option value >Select a currency</option>
     <option  *ngFor="let c of filter.ListPricelist[selectedPriceListIndex]?.currencies" value="{{[c.id]}}">{{ c.code }}</option>
   </select>
     <div *ngIf="submitted && f.currency.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
       <div *ngIf="f.currency.errors.required">Currency is required</div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

**project.component.ts**

```
  get f() {
    return this.registerForm.controls;
   }

 requiredFields(){
  this.registerForm = this.formBuilder.group(
   {
     title: ['',[Validators.required]],
     country: ['',[Validators.required]],
     pricelist: ['',[Validators.required]],
     currency: ['',[Validators.required]],
    }
   )
 }
```

**interface.model.ts**

```
  project: {
id: number;
code: string;
title: string;
country_id: number;
network_height_id: number;
country_label: string;
created_at: any;
createdby_id: number;
createdby_name: string;
currency_code: string;
currency_id: number;
pricelist_id: number;
pricelist_label: any;
total_fourniture: number;
updated_at: any;
updatedby_id: number;
updatedby_name: string;
pricelist: Array<{
  pricelist_id: number;
  label: string;
}>
};
```

Don't hesitate to tell me if you need anything else, thank you for your time

Comment: *then I use the [selected] option*: don't do that. It's the responsibility of Angular to select the appropriate option based on your model. If the value of the form control is === to the value of one of the options, then that option will be selected. The model if the point of truth. Note that `value="{{p.id === project?.pricelist_id}}"` doesn't make sense: all your options will have either the string 'true' or the string 'false' as their value.

Comment: @JBNizet Thank you, that's really helpful, so if I understand it right, `[selected]` is a "to not do" and I should keep only with `value`, am I right ?

Comment: Yes. Just like with inputs, you have bidirectional binding: if you type something in the imput, the for control value changes, and if you change the form control value, the what the input displays changes. Select works the same way.

Comment: Alright thank you, I'll do that

Comment: @JBNizet I tried but still don't understand how value should set the default `<select>` value, do you know any doc that can help me out ? I've been searching but cannot find any answers, sorry for asking you again

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rdhsvp

Comment: Thank's a lot once again, have a great day!